# Find the eigenvalues of...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> [image]

My characteristic equation starts off:

$$\lambda(\lambda(\lambda-3k)+3k^2)-k^3=0$$
Once expanded I get:
$$\lambda^3-3\lambda^2k+3\lambda k^2-k^3=0$$

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Factor!**
$$
0 = \lambda^3 - 3\lambda^2 k + 3\lambda k^2 - k^3 = (\lambda - k)^3
$$
so
$\lambda = k$ is the only root (eigenvalue).